# Merging different length dataframe in Python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframe:

```
df1
aa  gg   pm
1   3.3  0.5
1   0.0  4.7
1   9.3  0.2
2   0.3  0.6
2   14.0 91.0
3   13.0 31.0
4   13.1 64.0
5   1.3  0.5
6   3.3  0.5
7   11.1 3.0
7   11.3 24.0
8   3.2  0.0
8   5.3  0.3
8   3.3  0.3
```

and df2:

```
aa  gg   st
1   3.3  in
2   0.3  in
5   1.3  in
7   11.1 in
8   5.3  in
```

I would like to merge these two dataframe on col aa and gg to get results like:

```
aa  gg   pm   st
1   3.3  0.5  in
1   0.0  4.7    
1   9.3  0.2    
2   0.3  0.6  in
2   14.0 91.0   
3   13.0 31.0   
4   13.1 64.0   
5   1.3  0.5  in
6   3.3  0.5    
7   11.1 3.0  in
7   11.3 24.0   
8   3.2  0.0    
8   5.3  0.3  in
8   3.3  0.3
```

I want to map the col st details to based on col aa and gg.
please let me know how to do this.

Comment: @jezrael any other way around this? i tried with df1.loc[df1['aa'].isin(df2['aa']),'st'] = 'in'. as in df2 the st col as same val as in. i tried to use isin and loc to create a new col 'st' in df1. but onlyone col i am able to check. i need something like df1.loc[df1['aa','gg'].isin(df2['aa','gg']),'st'] = 'in'

Comment: yes.. not getting mapped

Comment: ok.. sure... i will wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can multiple float columns by `1000` or `10000` and convert to integers and then use these new columns for join:

```
df1['gg_int'] = df1['gg'].mul(1000).astype(int)
df2['gg_int'] = df2['gg'].mul(1000).astype(int)

df = df1.merge(df2.drop('gg', axis=1), on=['aa','gg_int'], how='left')
df = df.drop('gg_int', axis=1)
print (df)
    aa    gg    pm   st
0    1   3.3   0.5   in
1    1   0.0   4.7  NaN
2    1   9.3   0.2  NaN
3    2   0.3   0.6   in
4    2  14.0  91.0  NaN
5    3  13.0  31.0  NaN
6    4  13.1  64.0  NaN
7    5   1.3   0.5   in
8    6   3.3   0.5  NaN
9    7  11.1   3.0   in
10   7  11.3  24.0  NaN
11   8   3.2   0.0  NaN
12   8   5.3   0.3   in
13   8   3.3   0.3  NaN
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked. but my df1 and df2 were 'object' so i had to 1st convert them to float using df1['gg'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['gg'], errors='coerce').